# CLI command to convert Webp image(s) to JPG?

Tags: image, jpeg, webp

How do I convert webp files to JPG format?

Comment: I think the question is specific and therefore not too broad: it simply asks: How to convert webp to jpg.  However superuser.com would be a better home for it, assuming that it is not a programming question.

Comment: In WIndows, open the .webp file in MS Paint and save as .jpg. :-)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use **ImageMagick** v7:

```
magick input.webp output.jpg
```

Or **ImageMagick** v6:

```
convert input.webp output.jpg
```

---

If you have lots to do, use `mogrify` instead. So, say you want to convert all the WEBP images in the current directory to JPEG:

```
magick mogrify -format JPEG *.webp
```

And if you want the converted files in a directory called `OUTPUT`, use:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
magick mogrify -format JPEG -path OUTPUT *.webp
```

Comment: It does require that the webp and jpg delegates be installed with Imagemagick. See https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download. You can see if it is installed using `convert -version` or `magick -version` as indicted by Mark above

Comment: In case you have many files: ```for i in *.webp; do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`; echo "$name"; convert "$i" "${name}.jpg"; done```

Comment: @maaniB Actually there's a better way with `mogrify`, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: Convert single file:
`ffmpeg -i myfile.webp myfile.jpg`

Convert all files from the current directory recursively:
`find . -iname '*.webp' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -y -i "$1" "${1%.*}.jpg"' _ {} \;`

Comment: I assume ImageMagick is cross platform. In any case, should we add "operating system" tags to the question, to try to get it reopened?

Comment: For `-path` you may need to create the directory first.

Comment: sudo apt install imagemagick

Comment: It worked only for PNG, not JPEG. Am I missing an extension or something?